# VBA Call Function in Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Is it possible to use VBA in access to perform macros in excel, using a "call function"? I have am trying to format data, by using the VBA functions in Access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Here is an example:

```
Sub RunExcelMacro()
Dim xl As Object
'Step 1:  Start Excel, then open the target workbook.
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Book1.xlsm")

'Step 2:  Make Excel visible
    xl.Visible = True

'Step 3:  Run the target macro
    xl.Run "MyMacro"

'Step 4:  Close and save the workbook, then quit the Excel application
    xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
    xl.Quit

'Step 5:  Memory Clean up.
    Set xl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That works great! The only issue now, is that, I start with it closed because my boss wants as much automation as possible. When I run the code you gave me, it closed the wb immediately following the execution of the macro. Please advise.